# How to get the object related to hibernate search result list?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

I need to do a search for several documents indexed on elasticsearch. The search works, but I need to know the type of object that returns the search.

public List search(String terms) {

```
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    QueryBuilder authorQB = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
            .forEntity(Author.class).get();
    QueryBuilder postQB = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
            .forEntity(Post.class).get();
    QueryBuilder commentQB = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
            .forEntity(Comment.class).get();

    Query authorLQ = authorQB
            .keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1)
            .onFields(AUTHOR_FIELDS).matching(terms)
            .createQuery();

    Query postLQ = postQB
            .keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1)
            .onFields(POST_FIELDS).matching(terms)
            .createQuery();

    Query commentLQ = commentQB
            .keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1)
            .onFields(COMMENT_FIELDS).matching(terms)
            .createQuery();

    Query luceneQuery = authorQB.bool()
            .should(authorLQ)
            .should(postLQ)
            .should(commentLQ)
            .createQuery();

    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.
            createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Author.class, Post.class, Comment.class);

    List<Object> result; // need to know object type

    try {
        result = jpaQuery.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        throw new NoResultException("The search for " + terms + " did not get any results");
    }

    return result;
}
```

That gives me a list of all the objects, but I need to know exactly what type it is (Author, Post or Comment). It is possible to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `instanceof`... but if you really want Hibernate Search to return that, you can use projections:

```java
    FullTextQuery jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.
            createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Author.class, Post.class, Comment.class);
    jpaQuery.setProjection( ProjectionConstants.OBJECT_CLASS, ProjectionConstants.THIS );

    List<Object[]> results = jpaQuery.list();
    for ( Object[] result : results ) {
         Class<?> resultClass = result[0];
         Object resultObject = result[1];
         // ... do stuff ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for.